# integer to date format in R

Tags: r, date, integer

I want to change the column of "dob" to date format.
I used the below code but did not see changes in my data.

```
Date = as.Date(ped$dob)
```

Can you guide me through this?

```
        ID   sex  dob     yob 
1:  126000   M    20220523 2022    
2: 375000    M    20220523 2022
```

Comment: `as.Date(ped$dob, '%Y%m%d')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
note the big Y in the format

```
as.Date(as.character(ped$dob), '%Y%m%d')
```